# Element with flex-grow: 1 does not shrink to fit container size

Tags: css, flexbox

As you can see [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2f131s8k/), we have two elements displayed in a flex row. One element contains a text and should grow as much as possible, so `flex-grow: 1`. The other element should always stay to the right and consume as little space as possible, so `flex-shrink: 1`.

This works well, but sometimes, when the first element contains a very long text, the overall flex size exceeds the parent container's size. I can't see any reason why the browser does not just break the text differently.

[image]

The issue is reproducible with Firefox.

Is there an elegant way of fixing this?

Comment: I don't see the problem in your demo. Can you provide more details? Or an illustration.

Comment: I've just added a screenshot to illustrate the problem. "Remove" is not contained within the gray box, but the label could just be wrapped differently and Edit / Remove would fit perfectly.

Comment: I'm not getting that illustration in FF (51.0.1). There is no overflow of the parent. Try adding this to your code: `.element > * { min-width: auto; }`... https://jsfiddle.net/2f131s8k/2/

Comment: I'm sorry, the issue was in Safari and not Firefox, my bad. But I have very similar issues in Firefox, but I can't reproduce them isolated like this. Unfortunately, `.element > * { min-width: auto; }` doesn't work either in Safari.

Comment: Can you specify Safari version? Can't reproduce with Safari 11